# Trajectory formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

The vector of position is given by this formula: $\vec r=asin(\omega t)\hat x+acos(2\omega t)\hat y$.

I'm trying the trajectory formula. I get the next equaions

$\begin{cases}
x_{t}=asin(\omega t)\\
y_{t}=a(1-2sin^{2}(\omega t))
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}=sin^{2}(\omega t)\\
\frac{y+a}{2a}=sin^{2}(\omega t)
\end{cases}$

than I sub-struct them and get: $y=\frac{2x^{2}}{a}-a$

That's mean they the trajectory is parabula.

but I'm not sure that I'm allowed to square $x_t$. Is this way correct?

Comment: try simplifying with $1−2sin^{2}(\omega t)=cos(2\omega t)$

Comment: Your question is about algebra - reformulation of equations - not physics.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is right apart froma  sign. Even faster:

Without squaring
$$y_t=a(1-2sin^2(\omega t))=a(1-2{x^2\over a})=-2x^2+a$$

so it is a flipped parabula.